# How to differentiate whether the current user is in vf page tab view or detail page view?

Tags: case, detail-page, visualforce-tab

I have handled the case creation process using a vf page and explored it as a vf tab. Now i want to have a validation that should throw an error message that if the current user is in vf tab view , it should allow to edit the record but if the user is in the detail page view , it should not.

Kindly help me out!!!
I have tried validation rule as well as trigger. Nothing much happened !!

**Validation Rule :**

```
AND(NOT($User.BypassVR__c),IF($Profile.Name = "Core-Service Profile Community",True,False),
OR(ISCHANGED(AccountId),ISCHANGED(ContactId),
ISCHANGED(Priority),ISCHANGED(Type),ISCHANGED(Subject),ISCHANGED(Description),ISCHANGED(Answer__c),ISCHANGED(Origin),ISCHANGED(VIN__c),
ISCHANGED(Kilometer__c),ISCHANGED(CIRNumber__c),ISCHANGED( CatalogFuncCode__c),
ISCHANGED(VehicleMaintenance__c),ISCHANGED(CustomerWants__c ),ISCHANGED(MaintHistAvail__c ),
ISCHANGED(RetainedVehicle__c),ISCHANGED( RetainedVehDate__c),ISCHANGED(SubType__c),ISCHANGED(IS_Internal__c)), PRIORVALUE(Tech_IsDraft__c) <> false )
```

**Trigger :**

```
public with sharing class ecareCTR {

public static void caselistval(List<case> lCase) {
 Set<Id> lCaseId =  new Set<Id>();
 for(Case c:lcase)
     lCaseId.add(c.Id);
List<Case> lEcareCase = new List<Case> ();
List<Case> ecList = new List<Case>();
try {
ecList = [SELECT id,CaseNumber from Case WHERE id IN:lCaseId];
if(!ecList.isEmpty()) {
 for(Case cas :  ecList) {
    cas.Tech_IsDraft__c = false;
    lEcareCase.add(cas);
}           

  }

}
  catch (Exception e) {
      system.debug('eeee' + e);
  }
}
}
```

Above trigger is called from before update method

Comment: Try looking at the `url`. For example, if you are on a standard detail page, the url would be something like `https://XXX.salesforce.com/RECORD_ID`, while if you are in a custom VF page the `url` will be like `https://XXX.salesforce.com/apex/PAGE_NAME`.

Comment: Are you using standardcontroller or custom controller here?

Answer (score 0):

You can do one thing. Create a static variable and set it to true. Now refer this variable in your trigger and if its true then show error message that you can't update the record.

And from your VF page set this variable to false. So it will not give you any exception.

Comment: Ok tushar i ll create a static variable in trigger and set it to true if the user is trying to update. But how to use the same variable in the vf page ot make it false

Comment: @Sathish from your extension set this to false

Comment: Could you tell the syntax to declare  variable in the vf page, to  make it as false.

Comment: @Sathish VF page means before making DML from apex set it(Static Boolean variable) to false.

Comment: Sahrma This what I am declaring in {!tempvariable}=false vf page. And in my class   public static  boolean runOnce(){
  
              fts=true;  
              if(fts){
             fts=false;
             return true;
        }else{
            return fts;
    }
   }

Comment: This what I am declaring {!tempvariable}=false in vf page. And in my class   public static boolean fts;  public static boolean runOnce(){ fts=true; if(fts){ fts=false; return true; }else{ return fts; } } .Could you please correct the code because its not working.